# In laravel, I want to display multiple product images in slider which is store in JSON format in database

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-blade, e-commerce

I am trying to display my product images in a slider, which are stored in JSON format in the database table's column like this ["1.png","2.png","4.png","5.png"]. The images are being displayed but not according to my expectations.

I am integrating an e-commerce template, In this template, there is a product detail page. Here it is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg6Q2.png)

Here is template code

```
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="wrap-flexslider">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <div class="flexslider style-1 has-relative">
                                    <ul class="slides">
                                        <li data-thumb="images/shop/sh-detail/thumb-detail-01.jpg">
                                            <img src="images/shop/sh-detail/detail-01.jpg" alt="Image">
                                            <div class="flat-icon style-1">
                                                <a href="images/shop/sh-detail/detail-01.jpg" class="zoom-popup"><span class="fa fa-search-plus"></span></a>
                                            </div> 
                                        </li>
                                        <li data-thumb="images/shop/sh-detail/thumb-detail-02.jpg">
                                            <img src="images/shop/sh-detail/detail-01.jpg" alt="Image">
                                            <div class="flat-icon style-1">
                                                <a href="images/shop/sh-detail/detail-01.jpg" class="zoom-popup"><span class="fa fa-search-plus"></span></a>
                                            </div> 
                                        </li>
                                        <li data-thumb="images/shop/sh-detail/thumb-detail-03.jpg">
                                            <img src="images/shop/sh-detail/detail-01.jpg" alt="Image">
                                            <div class="flat-icon style-1">
                                                <a href="images/shop/sh-detail/detail-01.jpg" class="zoom-popup"><span class="fa fa-search-plus"></span></a>
                                            </div> 
                                        </li>
                                        <li data-thumb="images/shop/sh-detail/thumb-detail-04.jpg">
                                            <img src="images/shop/sh-detail/detail-01.jpg" alt="Image">
                                            <div class="flat-icon style-1">
                                                <a href="images/shop/sh-detail/detail-01.jpg" class="zoom-popup"><span class="fa fa-search-plus"></span></a>
                                            </div> 
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>                           
                                </div><!-- /.flexslider -->
                            </div>
                        </div>                              
                    </div><!-- /.col-md-6 -->
```

i tried this

```
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="wrap-flexslider">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="flexslider style-1 has-relative">
                                <ul class="slides">
                                    @foreach(json_decode($product->additional_images) as $image)
                                        <li data-thumb="{{ asset('uploads/product_images/' . $image) }}">
                                            <img src="{{ asset('uploads/product_images/' . $image) }}" alt="Image">
                                            <div class="flat-icon style-1">
                                                <a href="{{ asset('uploads/product_images/' . $image) }}" class="zoom-popup"><span class="fa fa-search-plus"></span></a>
                                            </div> 
                                        </li>
                                    @endforeach
                                </ul>                           
                            </div><!-- /.flexslider -->
                        </div>
                    </div>                              
                </div><!-- /.col-md-6 -->
```

but getting result of slides like this
[but getting result of slides like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCmdX.png)

Comment: What is the issue/question? Tags on the question seem incorrect. It seems like a CSS/HTML/JS issue. PHP could be generating incorrect HTML but not clear what HTML is suppose to be. Please define "my expectations".

Comment: Please elaborate your expectations as well.

Comment: _"Here is template code"_ - so you're saying, this static version worked as intended - but your dynamic one doesn't? Well then compare the resulting HTML of the dynamic one with that of the static version, and figure out what the significant differences are.